# Why is SQL Server Express replying with replacement character 65533 in php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, special-characters

I have a php script running on linux which queries a MSSQL Server Express database running on my dev machine (windows) using the php mssql driver.

I'm able to connect and select a database, and get no errors.

I put the query directly into a query window in MS SQL Server Management Studio and I get the correct data back. However, if I run the same query from my PHP script, the data that comes back has a bunch of "replacement characters", described here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm

It looks like this: �

For instance, when querying for a list of IDs, eg "SELECT DISTINCT PageId FROM Pages", the query window is showing a list of IDs in the following format:

**C961277D-D8BE-4337-82CF-003F6E7951E2**

However, when I run the **same query** in PHP, this is the result:

**'���K�@�t��@/**

I AM getting the same number of results, so the SQL Server seams to be interpreting the query correctly, but in the results, the character length is wrong, none of the characters match, and the format is wrong. Anybody have any idea what is going on?

Thank you for your help.

Relevant code here:

```
$this->connection = mssql_connect(
    $this->configuration['servername'],
    $this->configuration['username'],
    $this->configuration['password']);

$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT PageId FROM sf_CmsCtrlLinks';     

$result = mssql_query($query);

while ($row = mssql_fetch_object($result)){

    // Results in "page ID: 7��"�O�5,���"   
    echo "page ID: " . $row->PageId;

}
```

Comment: Can I see the code for your `php` script?

Comment: Added code, but Joachim got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server returns GUIDs to PHP in binary format.

If you want it as a readable format, you can just make MSSQL pass it back to you as a string;

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), PageId) as PageId FROM pages
```

If you don't need them readable, not casting them and just using them as an "opaque" id should work without problems.

I can't test it myself, but [mssql_guid_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-guid-string.php) may also work to convert them to readable form.